# Error [Plugin.hh:180] libvelodyne_plugin.so: No such file or directory Gazebo 8.1.1

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am following this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i5&cat=#Step5:Buildandtest

When I run Gazebo:

```
gazebo --verbose ../velodyne.world
```

This error appears:

```
[Err] [Plugin.hh:180] Failed to load plugin libvelodyne_plugin.so: libvelodyne_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16461/error-%5Bplugin.hh:180%5D-libvelodyne_plugin.so:-no-such-file-or-directory-gazebo-8.1.1/) by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is happening is that Gazebo can't find *libvelodyne_plugin.so*, this look for libraries in the directories indicate by **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** enviromental variable, so you need to **indicate where to find it changing  it**.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:~/velodyne_plugin/build
```

---

Originally posted by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) with karma: 5 on 2017-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0